# How to make button fill width

Tags: flutter, dart

I made this custom button:

```
class LockedSoundButton extends StatelessWidget {
  LockedSoundButton(
      {@required this.text, @required this.onPress, this.height});
  int height = 50;
  final String text;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 50,
        child: Row(children: [
          FlatButton(
            child: Row(children: [
              Icon(Icons.add, color: CustomColors.aSoundButtonLockedIcon),
              Text(
                this.text,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
              )
            ]),
            onPressed: () {
              this.onPress();
            },
            textColor: CustomColors.aSoundButtonLockedText,
            color: CustomColors.aSoundButtonLocked,
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

As you can see, I placed it inside a `SizedBox`, and setted the `width` to infinity. However, the button is getting the size of the `Icon` + `Text`.

Why won't it simply fill? A sized box:

> If either the width or height is null, this widget will try to size
> itself to match the child's size in that dimension

I also tried taking out `width` but I get the same effect

Comment: What is the parent of this widget?

Comment: @Ramin vertical ListView

Comment: Have you checked if the ListView has filled width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the useless single-child `Row` around the `FlatButton`. The Row is providing the constraints to the button that is preventing the button from expanding and this will expand the button to the full width provided. It's generally a bad idea to have a widget that takes multiple children as a parameter but only pass one. It's also not necessary to explicitly pass `double.infinity` as the width to the `SizedBox`.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 50,
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Row(children: [
            Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
            Text(
              "test",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            )
          ]),
          onPressed: () {
            print("stuff");
          },
          textColor: Colors.blue,
          color: Colors.black,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
        ));
  }
```

If you want to put space between the `Icon` and `Text` you can add a `Spacer`

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: 50,
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Row(children: [
            Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
            Spacer(),//Add spacer between widgets
            Text(
              "test",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w300),
            )
          ]),
          onPressed: () {
            print("stuff");
          },
          textColor: Colors.blue,
          color: Colors.black,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
        ));
  }
```